# VR breaks on unhandled exception in Debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm debugging a number of plugin dlls in a host application. When running in release mode, everything works like a charm. In Debug mode however, VS breaks on unhandled access violation exceptions of the host application all the time, so I never even get the chance to debug my own binaries. I've turned off all the exceptions in the "Break When Thrown" section of the Exception settings. Any idea what else I could do to make this work?

Comment: Are you using Debug versions of everything?

Comment: I do not have Debug binaries of the host application.